# TYPO3: OnePager Menu with menuDataProcessor

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I want to integrate a one-pager menu with the menu data processor. It should list all content elements of a site with jump marks as links.

With the following code, I get all content elements but I don't know how to pass them to the processor.

As I have not found anything about this I'm not sure if this is maybe impossible.

```html
page.10.dataProcessing.70 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
page.10.dataProcessing.70 {
    table = tt_content
    pidInList.field = uid
    as = content
    where = sectionIndex = 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can now output it in Fluid in this way.
You have to create the links yourself. TYPO3 usually sets the IDs in this format `<div id="c{UidOfContentElement}">...</div>` in the frontend.
You can then create the menu as follows

```
<f:if condition="{content}">
    <ul class="section">
        <f:for each="{content}" as="item">
            <li>
                <a href="/#c{item.data.uid}" title="{item.data.header}">
                    <span>{item.data.header}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </f:for>
    </ul>
</f:if>
```